# Mocha not recognizing a global variable when running tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

In my app I set up a global variable in it's own file. Which works fine in my app, but breaks my unit tests on the files which need it.

It is basically on the root level and in it's own file, which looks something like this:

```
global.MY_GLOBAL_VAR = require('my-global-var').MY_GLOBAL_VAR
```

This is later imported into my file that needs to be tested, and as mentioned before, works just fine when running the app normally. So it would look something like this:

```
// doSomething.js
require('MY_GLOBAL_VAR')

module.exports = function doSomething () {
// do stuff
}
```

So when I attempt to write a unit test for `doSomething.js`, I get the following error:

```
    1) "before all" hook
    GET /
     { TypeError: MY_GLOBAL_VAR is not a constructor
```

When I do a console.log on it, it's value comes back as `undefined`.
Interestingly enough, if I run `node doSomething`, the `MY_GLOBAL_VAR` is as expected (which is a function).

I have attempted to modify a bit my original test command, but to no avail. This is how it currently looks:

> "test": "mocha ---globals MY_GLOBAL_VAR -require @babel/register --require dotenv/config --require ./MY_GLOBAL_VAR.js --watch-extensions js \"{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.test.js\""

(Originally it didn't have the `--globals` args or the requiring of the `MY_GLOBAL_VAR` file.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I mean, the easy answer is, 'This is one reason why global variables are frowned upon'.

Comment: The error message suggests that `MY_GLOBAL_VAR` is recognized, but isn't a constructor. You say it's a function, which means your problem sounds like you have `new MY_GLOBAL_VAR()` in your code when it should be `MY_GLOBAL_VAR()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for the problem. It wasn't mocha that didn't recognize the global variable, but babel.

Nothing had to be changed in `package.json`, I was able to revert my test script back to how it originally was.

All that had to be done, was to add the `MY_GLOBAL_VAR.js` file to the `ignore` list in my `.babelrc` file. So basically:

```
// in .babelrc
{
  "plugins": [
     // [...] my plugins
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "./MY_GLOBAL_VAR.js"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```